# How do I pass a registered service singleton into another registered service's constructor in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, service-provider

I have recently been learning about the AppServiceProvider. I have registered a service in the AppServiceProvider which creates a singleton - an instantiated GuzzleHttp Client, like so:

```
$this->app->singleton('GuzzleHttp\Client', function($api) {
    return new Client([
        'base_uri' =>  env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST'),
        'auth' => [
            env('ELASTICSEARCH_USER'), 
            env('ELASTICSEARCH_PASS')
        ],
    ]);
});
```

This is connecting to an ElasticSearch API, and that currently works:

`$response = app('GuzzleHttp\Client')->request('GET');`

I have set up a facade called ElasticSearchFacade, which contains only the `getFacadeAccessor()`:

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'elasticSearch';
}
```

I have also registered `elasticSearch` in my AppServiceProvider, like so:

```
$this->app->bind('elasticSearch', function() {
    return new ElasticSearch();
});
```

This creates a new ElasticSearch instance. However, I would love to pass the `GuzzleHttp\Client` into the elasticSearch service. So I have tried adding the following to my ElasticSearch.php file:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ElasticSearch
{
    protected $client;

    public function __contruct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $response = $this->client->request('GET');
        die($response->getBody()->getContents());
    }
}
```

I have now changed the registered service to pass through the GuzzleHttp Client like so:

```
$this->app->bind('elasticSearch', function() {
    return new ElasticSearch(app('GuzzleHttp\Client'));
});
```

However I am getting the error:

> PHP Error:  Call to a member function request() on null

Comment: While this may not be the answer you were seeking, why not use `$this->client = app('GuzzleHttp\Client')` inside construct function? Since `app` is a global helper function, there is no need to inject it..? Alternatively, you could use `App::make`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor method is `__construct` not `__contruct`. You have not defined a custom constructor for your `ElasticSearch` class. So that member variable is `null`.

Side Note: do not call `env` outside of the configuration files.

To avoid having to make these `env` calls outside of configuration files you can just add configuration files as needed or add to current configuration files. Something like Elastic Search credentials can probably get added to the `services.php` configuration file:

```
<?php

return [
    ...

    'elasticsearch' => [
        'host' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST'),
        'user' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_USER'),
        'password' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_PASS'),
    ],

    ...
];
```

Now that you have these in the configuration you can use the configuration system to pull these values:

```
config('services.elasticsearch'); // that whole array of values
config('services.elasticsearch.host'); // just that host value

Config::get('services.elasticsearch');
app('config')->get(...);
```

There are multiple ways to access the configuration system.

Comment: Thank you! How would I get the env variables to the AppServiceProvider if not straight from the env file please?